# Using Sendkes.Send function in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, sendkeys

I have a wpf application.
In my TextBox, I want when user press "Enter" key, focus jumps to next tab index control, like pressing tab key, I use this code

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
     SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
{
     SendKeys.Send("+{tab}");
}
```

but this doesn't work.
could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the TraversalRequest:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);               
            UIElement keyboardFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

            if (keyboardFocus != null)
            {
                keyboardFocus.MoveFocus(tRequest);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

The TraversalRequest takes the FocusNAvigationDirection as its parameter, determining the direction in which you want to navigate.

Also, this is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest.aspx) on traversalRequest class.